# Select from table where difference of date and today

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the entire table where the difference from 'date' column and now is grater than 7.  I tried

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where  DATEDIFF(day, date, CURDATE())>=7
```

and didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as a general hint: Try to always include as much information as possible in your questions. "Didn't work" is not a bug report, but only a statement. Always include the error message when you ask about a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIFF` function takes 2 arguments. Try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable where  DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE())>=7";
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DateDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) Takes 2 arguments as input:

> DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)

You can try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
       FROM mytable 
       WHERE DATEDIFF(date, NOW()) >= 7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre passing three parameters to `DATEDIFF` where it only takes two.

Change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable where  DATEDIFF(day, date ,CURDATE())>=7";
```

to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable where  DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE())>=7";
```

[DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to
>   the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` is an option, but take a look at this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  date_column < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You can use `INTERVAL` to do date calculations in MySQL. In my opinion this is much easier to read and it works, too. ;)

Note that this will actually subtract 7 days from the current date. So if you want to get everything that happened since the 7th day before the current one (i.e. until 11:59 pm that day), you will need another approach (e.g. `DATEDIFF`). If you just want to go back the time 7 days take to pass (7 * 24 hours), then this will do what you need.